# Move Treeview branch to new node

Tags: vb.net, treeview

I have a treeview structure as follows.

A1

___A2

___B2

______A3

______B3

___C2

___D2

I would like to move, say, node B2 along with all its children to become a child of, say, D2.

I found solutions on forums stating that you just set B2's parent to D2 but in VS 2010 Parent is read-only.

Is there a simple instruction that will do this or do I have to copy the node into D2 and then copy all the children into the new B2, then remove B2? That currently seems to take quite a while since there are quite a few nodes on the branches to move so I'm hoping there's an instant method.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually it looks as though my requirement to use the 'Find' process to locate the recipient node was what was slowing this down a lot. I've altered this method and is satisfactory for my needs now. However it would still be good to know if there is a method for moving an entire branch in a single go. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming WinForms, you have to find the nodes you are dealing with, then remove the branch you want to move, and then add it to the other branch:

```
Dim nodeB2 As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find("nodeB2", True).FirstOrDefault
If nodeB2 IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim nodeD2 As TreeNode = TreeView1.Nodes.Find("nodeD2", True).FirstOrDefault
  If nodeD2 IsNot Nothing Then
    nodeB2.Parent.Nodes.Remove(nodeB2)
    nodeD2.Nodes.Add(nodeB2)
  End If
End If
```

Comment: Thx Lars. I tried something similar previously but it didn't seem to include the child nodes. However I just used the actual node B2 rather than B2.Parent.Nodes...... Will have a go at this in the morning. Thx again.

Comment: This works great. I think the issue preventing my earlier attempts with similar code was that I was removing the original B2 after adding it to D2. This may have resulted in removing both nodes when asked to remove B2.